# Plot arrowhead on the line between two geospatial points on Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, geospatial, lines

I am trying to plot arrowheads on the lines between two geospatial points (latitude, longitude pairs) on Matlab without success. To plot just the lines without the arrowheads, I am using the following:

```
path = loadGPSPoints();
[lttrk,lntrk] = track(path);    
geoshow(lttrk,lntrk,'DisplayType','line','color','r');
```

The track function builds a list of coordinates that allows the geoshow function to build a set of lines between these coordinates. However, I have no control over these lines. They are, apparently, one object. So I cannot add arrowheads to the end of each point in the path.

The annotation() function does not work because it does not add the arrow annotation as part of the map. That is, if a zoom in or out the map, for example, the arrow gets displaced.

I also tried the function arrow() function from http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278 but it apparently does not work with maps.

Finally, I looked into the quiverm() function but it does not allow me to specify two different coordinates. Its application seems incompatible to what I need.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To plot stuff manually to a `geoshow` figure, the trick is to use `mfwdtran` to convert the lat/long data to the figure coordinate system. Then you can use `arrow` like normal. Here is an example building on the example from http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/map/ref/track.html :

```
load coast
axesm('mercator','MapLatLimit',[28 47],'MapLonLimit',[-10 37],...
    'Grid','on','Frame','on','MeridianLabel','on','ParallelLabel','on')
geoshow(lat,long,'DisplayType','line','color','b')
waypoints = [36,-5; 36,-2; 38,5; 38,11; 35,13; 33,30; 31.5,32];
[X, Y] = mfwdtran(waypoints(:,1),waypoints(:,2));
arrow([X(1:(end-1)) Y(1:(end-1))], [X(2:end) Y(2:end)])
```

[image]

By the way, you can also specify a `Marker` property in your calls to `geoshow`. For example:

```
geoshow(waypoints(:,1),waypoints(:,2),'DisplayType','line','Marker','>','color','r')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That sort of solves the problem. However, the arrow function draws an arrowhead proportional to the initial zoom. For instance, if I change `axesm('mercator','MapLatLimit',[28 47],'MapLonLimit',[-10 37],...
    'Grid','on','Frame','on','MeridianLabel','on','ParallelLabel','on')` to `axesm('mercator','MapLatLimit',[-65 80],'MapLonLimit',[],...
    'Grid','on','Frame','on','MeridianLabel','on','ParallelLabel','on')` the result are arrowheads too big even to fit the path. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: I considered your second approach as well before, but, as you can see, the arrowheads do not always match the correct direction.

Comment: @Ricardo Great I'm glad it helped. You can tweak all the parts of the arrow according to the description in the help. Good luck!

Comment: [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/278) is the Link to the _arrow_ tool used in John Colby's answer.